# Large amount of memory being allocated when downloading images from URL

Tags: android, android-image

I have an activity in which the user presses a button which fetches a JSON response from a URL, and then downloads and saves all of the image URLs in that JSON. The downloading takes place in a separate class which extends `Thread`:

```
downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask(handler);
        task.start();
    }
});
```

`handler` is an inner static `Handler` that holds a `WeakReference` to the activity (used for displaying progress).

In the `DownloadTask`:

```
public DownloadTask(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String jsonString = // gets JSON from server

    urlsToDownload = new HashSet<String>();

    // do some stuff with the JSON to put each URL into the Set

    for (Iterator<String> i = urlsToDownload.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String urlString = i.next();

        // the following takes place in two static method calls,
        // but I've laid it all out here for easier interpretation.
        // I'm also removing all try/catch blocks, if (x != null) checks etc

        // first download the image from the web
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close() // (done in try-with-resource)
        connection.disconnect();

        // then save the image on the device
        File file = new File(App.context.getFilesDir(), "my/file/name.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.close() // (done in try-with-resource)

        // make a Bundle, add some progress info and send it in a Message
        handler.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

My problem is that this is using a very large amount of memory. When looking at the memory monitor in Android Studio, it spikes up to ~95MB when downloading/saving each image (~1.7MB). I used the allocation tracker to take a close look, and there is this one line which bothers me:

[image: (there are 6 images being downloaded)]

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? As far as I know, this is a "standard" way to download images in Android.

Comment: Why are't you using AsyncTask instead of replicating it with a handler?

Comment: Also, why are you taking a stream, turning it into a bitmap, then turning it into a file?  Just write the stream directly to disk.

Comment: Use DownloadManager for that. Here's the demo: http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

Comment: You need't to create a bitmap.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm not using an `ASyncTask` because this takes more than a few seconds, and `DownloadTask` is used by two different activities. That's a good point about writing the stream directly to disk though.

Comment: AsyncTask with executeOnExecutor to run it on its own thread would probably be easier/less likely to be buggy.  Anyway, some of the memory is definitely from the bitmap.   Remember 1.7MB on disk is not 1.7MB in memory, the in memory is 4*width*height bytes big.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm writing the stream directly to disk as you suggested and it's working wonderfully (seems obvious now!). Haven't looked into executeOnExecutor, but if you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You make intermediate Bitmaps from your files. That takes a lot of memory. Do not use Bitmaps but save the image bytes directly to file. You are probably downloading a jpg file i think.

Just make a loop in which you read chunks from the input stream and write them to the file output stream.

Comment: Sorry. I only saw the talking about AsyncTasks when i posted this. I now see that this had been mentioned two times before. I should not have posted this indeed. Sorry.